# Computing the properties of the 3D-projection of an ellipse.

Tags: geometry, conic-sections, projective-geometry

I have an ellipse that is rotated around the white axis (see image below) in 3-dimensional space by an angle `α`. The axis passes through the perimeter and one of the ellipse's focal points `F`. In the picture the angle of the original blue ellipse `E` is 0°. When rotated by 180° it would be mirrored to the other side of the axis. When rotated by 90° it would point away from the viewer (`P1` behind the axis), rotated by 270° it would point towards the viewer (`P1` in front of the axis). The red ellipse `E'` is being rotated by 60°. The positions of points `P1'` to `P4'` and of point `M'` can be easily computed using the cosine of `α`.

But to actually *draw* the ellipse these points are useless to me. What I need are the white points, that are the end points of the two main axes of the ellipse `E'` *being projected* onto the plane of ellipse `E`. But I did not find a way to compute the values of `a'`, `b'` and `β'` in relation to the angle of rotation `α` (`a`, `b` and `β` are known). I would really appreciate if anyone could help. Thank you.

[image: Illustration of the ellipse and its projection.]

Comment: Whith 4 points you can easily find the properties of the ellipse. Are you looking for the locus of the vertices of the ellipse as it is rotated, instead?

Comment: I have the properties of the vertices of both ellipses as lengths and angles from a central point and also as positions in a cartesian coordinate system. So I could use these to feed them to a formula that gives me either the positions of the new vertices or the lengths of both semi-axes and the angle β', that is both equally good. Could you point me to a resource that explains how to do it? I found [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/339126/how-to-draw-an-ellipse-if-a-center-and-3-arbitrary-points-on-it-are-given) but I don't understand it. Thanks.